# Authorization Type Basic in powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, invoke-webrequest

How to pass set below Postman Authorization Type Basie Username and password values in Power shell script?

[image]

```
$username = "laxjeurkaie"

$password = "pwdeoros243" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

ECHO $credential

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", $Authorization)
$headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")

ECHO $headers

$response = -1
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myUrl -Method GET -Credential $credential -Headers $headers 

ECHO $response
```

Comment: Have you tried [`-Authentication Basic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#-authentication)?